# Cannot Initialize type 'int' error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I have a simple code in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject
{
  public static class Class1
  {
    public static int[] Iparray = new int { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
  }
}
```

however on (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) the error displayed is

`Cannot initialize type 'int' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`

I am using vs 2010 and
and .NET framework 4

Thank you All

Comment: Without `[]` the compiler tries to do `int tmp = new int(); tmp.Add(12); tmp.Add(9); ...; Iparray = tmp;`. That's a _collection initializer_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing brackets. Like this:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us

Answer (score 3):

You have three ways to define an `int` array:

```
 public static int[] Iparray = { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };

 public static int[] Iparray = new[] { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
 public static int[] Iparray = new int[] { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new int[] { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
public static int[] a = new int[] {12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
```

instead of

```
public static int[] Iparray = new int { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missed square brackets;

```
namespace MyProject
{
  public static class Class1
  {
    public static int[] Iparray = new int[] { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
  }
}
```

- [`Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx)
- [`Single-Dimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0a7fscd0.aspx)

Alternative ways of declaring an `int` array;

- `int[] Iparray = { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };`
- `int[] Iparray = new[] { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };`

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
or this:

int[] values = new int[3];
values[0] = 1;
values[1] = 2;
values[2] = 3;
```

and have a look on this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add [] to your code

```
public static int[] Iparray = new int[] { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
```